# Does PyCharm 1.x / 2.x provide a debug console?

Tags: pycharm

In the debug mode, I need to use interactive console to check values of different variables instead of depending on watch window.

Is there such a function out there?

Thank you

// Updated for PyCharm 2.0 //

You can invoke it by pressing 'Show command line' button in a toolbar of console output window, which is described in online help on page http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/debug-tool-window-console.html

Comment: The "Show command line" button is just what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. There's a button in the left toolbar of the Debug toolwindow that shows the console in the process being debugged.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Tools -> Run Python Console it will import your project, but not sure that is what you need.  Other wise while live debugging you can watch and inspect with the debug view.

Comment: The Tools->Run Python Console is not connected with Debug. While you debug a variable, you are not able to "print variable" in that console.